# How to configure Shadow plugin using kotlin dsl

Tags: kotlin, gradle, shadowjar

I can't figure out how to use the **shadow** plugin inside a gradle build with kotlin DSL.
All the documentation is using the groovy dsl.

This is the content of build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject
import org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar

plugins {
    // Apply the Kotlin JVM plugin to add support for Kotlin.
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"

    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    application
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
        // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
        jcenter()
    }
    group = "com.example"
    version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

dependencies {
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))

    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.MainKt")
}


tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                mapOf(
                    "ImplementationTitle" to project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version" to project.version)
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the content for `src/main/kotlin/com/example/Main.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example

fun main() {
    println("Hello world")
}
```

But when I try to do `gradle build`, I get this error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar' (type 'ShadowJar').
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
```

which I think is weird, since I've already entered the application main class inside the `application` argument.

I've tried to add this:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<ShadowJar>() {
    mainClassName = "com.example.MainKt"
}
```

But when I try to build with this option, it complains that it can't find the `ShadowJar` type.

```
  Line 22: tasks.withType<ShadowJar>() {
                          ^ Unresolved reference: ShadowJar
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try with `tasks.withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {}` or import that package at the top of script.

Comment: Just add an import for `ShadowJar`. In fact, the IDE should suggest it to you, a benefit of using Kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to add `mainClassName` to the `ShadowJar` task, it should have been added to the `application` function. Like this:

```kotlin
application {
    val name = "com.cognite.ingestionservice.MainKt"
    mainClass.set(name)

    // Required by ShadowJar.
    mainClassName = name
}
```

The `mainClassName` property is deprecated, but is still required by ShadowJar as of version **6.1.0**.

`mainClass.set()` is not necessary when adding `mainClassName`, but it was in the documentation for gradle 6.7, so I added it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend in your simple case to configure default `shadowJar` and `jar` tasks (not all tasks of `ShadowJar` and `Jar` type, since you are not creating other instances).

```kotlin
tasks {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                mapOf(
                    "Main-Class" to "com.example.MainKt", //will make your jar (produced by jar task) runnable 
                    "ImplementationTitle" to project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version" to project.version)
            )
        }
    }
    shadowJar {
        manifest.inheritFrom(jar.get().manifest) //will make your shadowJar (produced by jar task) runnable
    }
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.example.MainKt" //will make run & runShadow tasks work. Have no idea why it can't take main class from jar/shadowJar manifests
}
```